# Risk difference setting up subdomain or new domain?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, domain

I have a single server Sharepoint Foundation 2013 instance that I've recently setup for my organization.  I'm still pretty new to Sharepoint.

I've been tasked with setting it up to allow apps, and have read helpful information from a number of sources, including here: [How do I turn on SharePoint App store in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013)

There appears to be a certain simplicity in just setting up a subdomain for apps, and I'm inclined to go that route, but I don't want to learn 6 months from now that I've made a horrible mistake, and one that I can't just undo.

- For a small organization running an internal sharepoint site, is there significant risk in using a subdomain vs a dedicated apps domain?
- If for some reason I go with the subdomain, and then in 6 months determine that I'd rather have a dedicated apps domain, is it impossible or especially difficult to transition?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is yes to both.

Here is a good read about SharePoint app domains: [SharePoint 2013 Apps Domain vs Subdomains](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) Towards the end, it shows you how to change the url to the app domain, which, should address your second question.