# After downloading and installing an app in sharepoint i cannot open it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

> I am using SharePoint 2013, and i want to configure high-trust apps for SharePoint.
>   I followed those msdn articles :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp179923

> My problem now is the following:

After downloading and installing any app from the app store or even deploying it from Visual Studio, when i want to open the app it displays a blank page and shows the following error message:

> This page can’t be displayed.
>
> Make sure the web address http://apps-95e7c833b3f075.sp.local is correct.

So as you can see my domain is `sp.local` and my app prefix is `apps`...

Sorry my problem is a bit wide-open.
I do have an `App Management Service` and `Subscription Settings Service` running on the server.
I fellow the msdn articles and every thing was set like it is mentioned.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

you can try and follow this post, its very lenghty in the first link that i provided in my answer but it should setup your app domain properly!

[How do I turn on SharePoint App store in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013/55025#55025)

as noted there is somthing not right with the configuration of your app domain! just follow the guide... its long but with images and in detail!

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS issue. Things to check:

- If you ping sp.local do you get a response?
- In the DNS, do you have a record *.sp.local ?
- **Have you followed [these steps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)?**

> 1. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click DNS.
> 2. In DNS Manager, right-click Forward Lookup Zones, and then click New Zone….
> 3. Accept the default of Primary zone, and then click Next.
> 4. In the Zone name box type the name for your new app domain name (for example, ContosoApps.com), and then click Next and create the
>      Zone.
> 5. In DNS Manager, under Forward Lookup Zones, right-click the new app domain name, and then click New Alias (CNAME).
> 6. In the New Resource Record dialog box, in the Alias name (uses parent domain if left blank) box, type *. The Fully qualified domain
>      name (FQDN) box displays *. followed by the domain name that you
>      created for apps. For example, *.ContosoApps.com or
>      *.Contoso-Apps.com.

- Can you ping apps-95e7c833b3f075.sp.local ? What is the response?
- Do you have any alternate access mappings?