# SharePoint 2013 - Cannot add SharePoint Store Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app

I have a SharePoint Farm with one single SharePoint server, and one separate database server. I am trying to set up apps for one of the web-applications, and have followed all the instructions on this link: [How do I turn on SharePoint App store in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013)

I have also confirmed everything in here: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

I still get the "Sorry, apps are turned off". There are NO errors in either the trace log, nor the Event-log, as I can find.

Anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found out. In this case, I had a custom service application connection setup for the web application. The App Management service application was not created before the web application, so the web application was not connected to the app management service.

I edited the service application connections, and then everything was good.