# Unable to add my first app to my app catalog "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps."

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-addin, administration, app

I have created a new web application inside my SharePoint 2013 on-premises. Then I created a new app catalog for my new web application. now I went to the app catalog and I add a new .app file as following:

[image]

Then I went to a site collection inside my new web application >> Add App >> from your organization >> I select the new app. But I got this error:

> Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps.

As followingly:

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you setup APP environment?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti the way i understand things is that App environment have to do with creating the app catalog site for my web application is this correct?

Comment: Creating an App Catalog site is only one step in the complete App environment setup process. Can you look at my answer below and verify that you have completed all steps mentioned in the MSDN article.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti thanks for the info, so which link provide the necessary steps? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx OR https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013 so i can follow one of the links instead of having to check the 2 links?

Comment: We do follow this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx. The second link is just for reference to point the same issue.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti thanks for your help will apply this inside my environment and check if this will allow me to add the app inside my sites... thanks again for the great help

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti now i am following the steps mentioned here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx .. now inside the DNS i need to create a new zone name. now my sharepoint web application can be accessed using this url `http://Ourservername/` .. so what i should define for the zone name?? should/can it be something such as `OurservernameApp.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60826/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-john-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with APPs in SharePoint on-premises server you have to follow below steps.

Below are steps to work with apps on your farm

1. Configure the domain
2. Configure SSL certificate settings (if your site is running on https protocol)
3. Configure APP services.

[MSDN article on setup APP environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)

[How do I turn on SharePoint App store in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013)