# How to enable apps in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-framework

I get this message "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps." when trying to add a my SpFX-app to a site.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are more than one approach to solve this problem
Please,review this link

[How do I turn on SharePoint App store in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/how-do-i-turn-on-sharepoint-app-store-in-sharepoint-2013)

BR

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)